# Need to Delete Email History Via Regular Expression

Tags: regex, email, text, replace

I have a whole bunch of text files that contain old emails. I need to delete the history that follows each main email.

So for example... I have lines that look like this:

```
  > Some random text
```

and this..

```
  >>> More random text
```

I'm trying to create a regular expression that matches these lines so I can delete them. The first one I came up with was this:

```
\s+>+.+\n
```

This ALMOST does the trick. Where it fails is when I have the following situation.

```
  > Text...
  >
  >  More random text.
```

It matches all of the first line and all of the third line. Weirdly... It matches right after the > in the second line.

What that means is that I have a bunch of random '>' characters throughout the file.

So then I tried this instead:

```
\s*>*.*\n
```

That matched literally every single line in the document. I was left with an empty file at the end.

What am I doing wrong? How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: what are your trying to achieve? post an example along with expted output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct

```
\s+>+.+\n                          //almost correct
```

This almost did the trick but failed to match the following:

```
  >
```

because `>.+` expects atleast one character after `>`

So, change your `.+` (one or more) to `.*`(zero or more) and it will work.

```
\s+>+.*\n                           //working
```

`\s*>*.*\n` This fails because `*` means zero or more.. and it containls all `nothing` instances

**EDIT**: You can also remove `\n` for better substitution i.e. use `\s+>+.*`.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your regex like below.

```
[ \t]*>+.*\n
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eX8bR6/2)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: `^\s*>+.*?(\n|$)`.

You can see an example [here](https://regex101.com/r/aJ5tP2/1).